# Why doesn't the VS Code Cpptools extension show function doc comments for functions with overloads?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Does anyone know how to remove overloads in the quick info popup for vscode? If I hover over a function with no overloads, it shows the comment description I wrote for the function using `/**`. But if I hover over a function with overloads, they just show the function signatures for all the overloads.

C/C++ Extension Version: `v1.15.4`

Example Code:

```
/**
    @brief This is a function.
*/
void foo(int x) {}


/**
    @brief This is a function.
*/
void foo(float x) {}
```

Screenshots:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue with the help of a maintainer. It was because my intelliSenseEngine was set to `Tag Parser` instead of `default`.

Comment: @starball https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11071

Comment: thanks. I've updated my answer post to also add that info.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: This is a known issue related to current performance limitations. Wait patiently and the fix will come in the future.

If you google "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues overload comment hover`", you'll find (it was the top search result for me) [Doc comments don't show for overloaded methods #6008](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6008), where [a maintainer (@sean-mcmanus) wrote](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6008#issuecomment-680253765):

> We're currently only show doc comments for the "active signature", but for when the overloads differ by type, we end up choosing the wrong overload (i.e. [#2206](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2206)).
>
> We intentionally skipped sending additional overload doc comments because it potentially could take too long. We had the idea of sending the doc comments if they able to get computed in < 1 second, but we were worried that users might get confused by the inconsistent results.
>
> We're expecting that this will get fixed after we fix the performance issue with doc comments later on.

---

Apparently if your `C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine` setting is set to `Tag Parser`, changing it to `default` may give you the desired behaviour ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/11071#issuecomment-1588079680)).